# Pervasive database: Problem with spaces in column names

Tags: odbc, field, spaces, pervasive

We use pervasive Database with Zen Contol-Center And want to perform the following SQl-Statenemt:

```sql
insert into MWlog
(Signatur,Datum,Uhrzeit,Auftrag,Probe,Parameter,Matrix,`Messwert neu`,Zugriff,`Messwert alt`,Aenderungsgrund)  
values 
('ML','2020-12-01','15:04:50','230176','230176','Bas. wirk.','TM','5.62','5','5.62','Neuer Import')
```

We get the following error-message:

```
*<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
insert into MWlog(Signatur,Datum,Uhrzeit,Auftrag,Probe,Parameter,Matrix,`Messwert neu`,Zugriff,`Messwert alt`,Aenderungsgrund)  values ('ML','2020-12-01','15:04:50','230176','230176','Bas. wirk.','TM','5.62','5','5.62','Neuer Import') 
[Zen][SQL Engine]
Syntax Error: insert into MWlog(Signatur,Datum,Uhrzeit,Auftrag,Probe,Parameter,Matrix,<< ??? >>`Messwert neu`,Zugriff,`Messwert alt`,Aenderungsgrund)  values ('ML','2020-12-01','15:04:50','230176','230176','Bas. wirk.','TM','5.62','5',
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>*
```

What is wrong in the SQL Statement?
(We found out that the problem are the spaces in the field-Names)

We are using

> Zen Control Center
> Zen Install Version 14.10.035.
> Java Version 1.8.0_222.

Comment: [This article](https://communities.actian.com/s/article/What-are-the-PervasiveSQL-Dictionary-Naming-Conventions-4229) says that "A delimited identifier is an identifier surrounded by double quotes.", so it looks like you should be using double-quotes instead of backticks to quote your column names, e.g., `"Messwert neu"`.

Comment: no we don't use double qoutes

Comment: "no we don't use double qoutes" - Based on what I see in the documentation, that's what you should be using. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

Gord Thompson is correct.  You need to use double quotes around field names with spaces or field names that are reserved key words.  You statements should be:

```
insert into MWlog
(Signatur,Datum,Uhrzeit,Auftrag,Probe,Parameter,Matrix,"Messwert neu",Zugriff,"Messwert alt",Aenderungsgrund)  
values 
('ML','2020-12-01','15:04:50','230176','230176','Bas. wirk.','TM','5.62','5','5.62','Neuer Import')
```